# Rails 5 does not reference a modified ActiveRecord-jdbc-adapter

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, activerecord-jdbc

### problem overview

I have a client with an App I'm trying to get to Rails 5.   Historically we modified the activerecord-jdbc-adapter to access a Progress OpenEdge database, and it's been working since Rails 3.2.  Currently, I can create a new activerecord-jdbc-adapter gem (v 52.8.xxx) and bundle it with Rails 5.2.8.1, but the error messages I get indicates that it is not using the src/java/arjdbc/jdbc/RubyJdbcConnection.java that I've modified.   Looking at the Rails 5 repository, the Gemfile at the root includes the activerecord-jdbcxxxx-adapters for platform Jruby, which should also pull in the generic adapter.   My theory is that despite bundling in my custom adapter, it's using code that is included with the various active* and action* gems that make up Rails 5.

I guess I'm hoping I'm wrong and someone can tell me I missed something basic.  Otherwise I'm inclined to switch to ODBC and drop Jruby, which is a change I'm not loving.

steps to demonstrate the issue:

### in activerecord-jdbc-adapter clone, check out 52-stable

Modify RubyJdbcConnection.java -- add a bunch of comments just to make it different

```
rake adapters:build
```

### in rails 5.2 app repo, using 'jdbc' as adapter in database.yml

#### Gemfile

```
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2'
gem 'activerecord', '~> 5.2'
gem 'activerecord-jdbc-adapter', '= 52.8.xxxxx', :platform => :jruby
```

#### commands

```
bundle install
RAILS_ENV=test rails c
MyModel.first # Model that is backed by the jdbc database
```

Because the adapter has not been modified to support the OpenEdge database, it fails.
The line number in RubyJdbcConnection matches unmodified source, not the file we modified above.